# How do I compile a Github Source Code/Repository to an apk file?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, apk

Good day,

I'm looking for help on recompiling a github source code/repository to an APK file.

I'm currently working on an app and I am using the Dolphin source code as a reference since its really organized and close enough of a reference to what I already have.

The format for my source code is basically like theirs as seen here: https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin

I have no idea on how to compile those files to a signed or unsigned apk.

I tried using Android studio (v3.6.3) before but got lost on what to do and gave up for a week..... so now I'm looking for some help. I would like if someone could teach me the process, so I could practice converting the Dolphin github repository to an apk and then apply that knowledge to progress into creating an alpha build of my app for testing.

PS. I'm a bit new to coding and App creation (learning on my own right now, especially during the quarantine where I live) so I'd really appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can either use ./gradlew build or android studio / build / apk

Comment: Could you explain more on the "/gradlew build"? Android Studio hasn't been working out for me when trying to build the apk/app.

Comment: I'm partial to explain you that: you must make Android Studio work somehow, and giving us the exact error you face with it will help. Studio provides a few conveniences: it allows you to auto download the sdk, accept the license, etc. Gradle won't build an apk easily. Maybe restart from scratch on a small project rather than this Dolphin one ? By the way Dolphin themselves give you this: https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin/blob/master/AndroidSetup.md . But if you can't compile a java program, are you sure you should start on such a complex emulator ? Shouldn't you try to show a button first

Comment: Thanks for the respose I actually wasn't aware of the Androidsetup.md so I'll look into it. Also I understand with starting on a simpler project and I'll look into starting over and taking it one step at a time, however right now that is what I was gearing to do and already started ... so to go back to the starting point from here won't be easy for me
Error I think I get with compiling; see here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/uPZUTc4k8P4RTbqTA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is written by C++/C. You cannot make it a APK. But instead you can write another app as a "wrapper application" to launch your C++/C project. By calling shell command or NDK.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood anything, but are you saying that through using a "wrapper application" I can create an apk with it instead of my previous methods?
Because my end goal is to get an apk out of it...

Also, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yes exactly. Check how this emulator works. I think they have user menu for it. What you can do is to create a launcher app from where this emulator can be invoked. Then make this launcher app a APK.